# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS works but no internet access. My wifi Internet connect works with my Win10

Tags: networking, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and all works but I do not have a internet connection so I can not do updates.

The same computer hardware running Win10 connects to the internet fine.
So my WiFi router and computer interface card must be working fine.

I tried the command window with "info nm-applet" and that file does not seem to be present.

Also at the menu at the top right of the desktop I do not see any network icon or any WiFi signals listed.  I see all of this when I am using  win10.

Am I missing the  nm-applwt file an any other internet connecting files from my 16.04 LTS download? How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci -knn`.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the network manager using:

sudo  systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

Comment: THIS IS WHA I GOT ----------To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

william@william-GA-970A-UD3:~$ sudu systemctl restart networkmanager.service
No command 'sudu' found, did you mean:
 This is what i got ------- Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'tudu' from package 'tudu' (universe)
sudu: command not found
william@william-GA-970A-UD3:~$

Comment: It's "sudo", not "sudu"